# In Mui, how do I use theme values in my css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My React app is using mui themes; index.js contains:

```
let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#00aaa0",
      contrastText: '#fcf4d9',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#D55B3E",
      contrastText: '#fcf4d9',
    },
  },
});

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

ReactDOM.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In one of my components (footer) I want to be able to add a top border which is in the primary colour.  So far footer.tsx contains:

```
const Footer= () => {

  return (
    <div className="pageFooter">Footer Text</div>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

I want to style "pageFooter" so that it uses theme.palette.primary.main as a top border colour.  With regular css I would link in my css file containing:

```
.pageFooter {
  border-top: 2px solid "#00aaa0";
}
```

but I want to make sure that the colour is always the same as the primary colour, so I want to do something like this:

```
.pageFooter {
  border-top: 2px solid theme.palette.primary.main;
}
```

This doesn't work, though, presumably because the theme is not available to the css file.  I've read the docs and I can't really follow them.  Can anyone explain what I should be doing here?

Comment: No official support yet. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12827) issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({ 
   pageFooter: {
     borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
   }
});

const Footer= () => {
    const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className={classes.pageFooter}>Footer Text</div>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solved it.  Just one note: I had to do `import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";` (instead of @material-ui/core) because I'm using mui rather than material-ui.

Comment: Also had to do `const useStyles:any` and `makeStyles((theme:any)` to pass TypeScript checks

Answer (score 4):

It's supported now by MUI v5.6.0 as an *experimental* feature. They export theme variables as CSS variables. Read [the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/overview/).

Example:

```
/* external-scope.css */
.external-section {
  background-color: var(--mui-palette-grey-50);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the MUI docs:

> @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5.

and also

> @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

MUI use JSS for styling. so we don't have access to theme in CSS files.
my solution:
you can define a CSS variable same color as your theme palette color. then use it in CSS files.

```
:root {
    --primary-main: #00aaa0;
  }
.pageFooter {
  border-top: 2px solid var(--primary-main);
}
```